# SL4A - Scripting Layer for Android

Tags: android, scripting

I read an article from the web on SL4A (which is  also known as Android Scripting Environment).

The site from where i got an article is:
http://infoworld.com/d/developer-world/php-development-comes-google-android-652

But i got the theorical knowledge only for SL4A (ASE)....

Anybody having practical idea or practical example, pls suggest to me.

1. Which are the scripting language supported by ASE?
2. How do i download script ?
3. How do i use script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you install the scripting environment you have shell scripting available (like bash).  You can then install other languages as well.  Currently it supports Python, Perl, JRuby, Lua, Javascript, Beanshell and Tcl.

Comment: does it support bash ? can I write an sh script calling sl4a ?

Comment: The original post was over 10 years ago and I don't think sl4a is maintained any more.  If you want to run bash scripts then maybe try termux, which is a full linux terminal on your android device.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux